# Photons. What are they?

Tags: particle-physics, photons

Photons are described as packets of energy and photon with a frequency has mass, momentum and kinetic energy. If they are particles, how can they have frequency? If they are waves with a frequency, how can they have mass?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is a photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273032/)

Comment: Did you do a web search on "photon"? Also check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon

Comment: Photons don't have mass.  I'm curious to know why you think they do.   Also, the energy transferred can't be described as kinetic energy.   I'd like to know where these ideas came from;  if they come from a published source I'd like to take a look at it to see if the information there is just wrong, or if it's just poorly presented.